# How to translate "BOTH AM & PM" or " AM ONLY" or "PM ONLY" into Brazilian Portuguese?

Tags: tradução, tradução-inglês

My question pretty much has all the samples.

I was wondering if there was a better way to translate instead of using:

> AM ONLY = APENAS DE MANHÃ
>
> PM ONLY = APENAS DE TARDE  or APENAS NÁ TARDE?

Or do you guys think that Brazil is already well acquainted with AM and PM and leaving such translations as the ones below is perfectly fine?

> AM e PM
>
> Apenas AM
>
> Apenas PM

Comment: My thoughts on this is that even if "Apenas AM" could be understood, there is not a need to be lazy.

Comment: In fact you'll need *tarde/noite*, as we say *uma da tarde*, but *onze da noite*.

Comment: Conforme horário ou luminosidade 03:00 AM pode ser manhã ou madrugada (podem dizer que é noite por causa da escuridão); 06:00 AM é manhã até 11:59; 12:00 AM até 12:59 AM é  meio dia ou meio dia e cinquenta e nove, 12:50 é dez pra uma da tarde ou meio dia e cinquenta; 01:00 PM é uma da tarde ou treze horas; 06:00 PM é dezoito horas ou seis horas da noite (pode ouvir alguém chamar de seis tarde se estiver sol)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most brazilians have no idea what "a.m." and "p.m." stand for. Even those who do will find it strange to see them being used in Portuguese.  You'll be safe saying:

> - pela manhã e à tarde
> - somente pela manhã
> - somente à tarde

You'll be even safer if you specify:

. aberto pela manhã de 8 às 12 h.

. acessível à tarde, das 15 às 18 h.

If all you say is "pela manhã", some people won't be sure whether you mean from 7.00, 8.00 or 9.00 a.m.  Likewise, "à tarde" can mean from 12 noon, 1 p.m., or 2.00 p.m.

Comment: How would we then translate AM and PM  in a short version? AM Only, PM Only?

Comment: @Hugo I've edited.

Comment: @Hugo : Just reinforcing what Centaurus said, consider to specify the time range when you say "apenas à tarde" or "apenas pela manha".

Answer (score 3):

There is no translation to that, the correct Time format in Portuguese is the 24h format so this translation is unnecessary in Portuguese. 
The representation should be :

7:00h or 19:00h
07:00h is acceptable too.

Comment: Finally someone saying that 24h format should be preferred. (Well Centaurus wrote it in 24h format) But this doesn't answer the question

Comment: @BrunoCosta Well, we can't blame Carlos. To be honest, I still haven't understood the question. And, judging by how dissimilar those answers are to each other, I believe I'm not the only one.

Comment: The correct grammar "grafia" for time is hh:mm:ss Does not exist AM or PM. If someone is trying to do a representation of 7AM should write 07:00 or 7:00. So, "de manhã" ou "à tarde" seams appropriate.

Comment: @CarlosMartins : I don't have references now, but I learned that one formal syntax to write times in Brazil is placing the 'h' among the hour and minutes, like: 12h00, 7h00, 10h30. I already read a lot of formal documents, contracts and others that use this format which I learned around 80's at school. I never checked if some revision in the language changed it, but the google calendar accepts this syntax, so...

Comment: @CarlosMartins : Encontrei isso de 2009 e cita o Inmetro, é o formato que falei 12h30, 7h40 ou 7h40m6s  https://www.uebbi.com/gramatica-qual-a-grafia-correta-das-horas/

Comment: Bem explicado @Luciano Obrigado pelo comentário.

Answer (score 0):

Brazilian Portuguese language does not adopt the AM/PM notation:

> 12 AM = meia noite
>
> 1 AM = 1 da manhã
>
> 5 AM = 5 da manhã
>
> 9 AM = 9 da manhã
>
> 12 PM = meio dia
>
> 1 PM = 1 da tarde
>
> 4 PM = 4 da tarde
>
> 6 PM = 6 da tarde
>
> 7 PM = 7 da noite
>
> 11 PM = 11 da noite

Comment: It's easy to generalize with that statement but when you have big media outlets in Brazil like O Globo using am and pm it makes it hard to say whether or not such can be accepted. In fact in my opinion, it makes it more acceptable. Source: http://blogs.oglobo.globo.com/top-spin/post/com-entrada-franca-challenger-do-rio-comeca-hoje-veja-programacao-470347.html and many others..

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Exchange da Língua Portuguesa, Luiz. Aqui vai uma dica de formatação: você não precisa inserir HTML para dar parágrafo, é só apertar Enter duas vezes que o editor começa a escrever na linha de baixo.

Comment: This does not answer the question